# What are the things I can do by mounting /var/run/docker.sock as a volume to a docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

After mounting /var/run/docker.sock to a running docker container, I would like to explore the possibilities. Can I issue docker commands from inside the container, like `docker stop`?  Why is it considered a security risk:- what exact commands could I run as a root user in docker that could possibly compromise the host?

Answer (score 1):

It's trivial to escalate access to the docker socket to a root shell on the host.

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged --pid host debian nsenter -t 1 -m -u -n -i bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't give you exact commands to execute since I'm not testing this but I'm assuming you could:

- Execute docker commands, including mounting host volumes to newly spawned docker containers, allowing you to write to the host
- Overwrite the socket to somehow inject arbitrary code into the host
- Escalate privileges to other docker containers running on the same machine